# Clarification of intermediate files in make-3.81

Tags: makefile

In our system we create a particular subsystem file as an .o file, say `sub.o`. And `sub.o` depends on components `compA.o`, `compB.o`, and `compC.o` and each of those components has a few dependencies. When we make the full system, `compA.o`, `compB.o`, `compC.o`, and `sub.o` exist in the directory. If I were to delete `compA.o` and try to remake the system, it will say there is nothing to be done and `compA.o` still does not exist. This is because `compA.o` is considered a intermediate file. I understand that the source files are never changed and the end result is fine.

What I don't understand is why the file `compA.o` is considered intermediate only on the remake of the system. If it was considered intermediate on the initial build shouldn't it not exist after that build, given [this definition](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Chained-Rules.html) of intermediate files?

I should mention that this only existed after we moved from make-3.79 to make-3.81.

Relevant output for make -d sub.o:

```
Looking for an implicit rule for 'compA.o'.
Trying pattern rule with stem 'compA'.
Found an implicit rule for 'compA.o'.
    Looking for an implicit rule for '../pas/compA.c'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem 'compA'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite '../pas/compA.w'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem 'compA.c'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite '../pas/RCS/compA.c'.
    Trying pattern rule with stem 'compA'.
    Trying implicit prerequisite '../pas/compA.w'.
    Looking for a rule with intermediate file '../pas/compA.w'.
       Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
       Trying pattern rule with stem 'compA.w'.
       Trying implicit prerequisite '../pas/RCS/compA.w'.
    No implicit rule found for '../pas/compA.c'.
```

and later...

```
Prerequisite 'compA.o' of target 'sub.o' does not exist.
No need to remake target 'sub.o'.
make-3.81: 'sub.o' is up to date.
```

Comment: Can you post the snippet of your makefile that is related to these files? Or post the output from running `make -d` in the various cases? Did the make that initially created `compA.o` complete successfully? Because if it was interrupted that could explain things. What behaviour did make `3.79` have exactly?

Comment: @EtanReisner All makes were completed successfully. In 3.79 if a .o file dependency was deleted it would be rebuilt upon making the target. I'd rather not give out the make but I can say the following lines appeared

`Prerequisite 'compA.o' of target 'sub.o' does not exist.`

`No need to remake target 'sub.o'.`

Comment: The intermediate `.o` file would be rebuilt even if the source hadn't changed? Which would then, I assume, force a rebuild of `sub.o` even though it didn't need to be done?

Comment: If `compA.o` exists already when `make` is run then the rule about deleting the intermediate file doesn't apply. See "The second difference is that if make *does* create *b* in order to update something else, it deletes *b* later on after it is no longer needed." from your link. So the question is why was it still there in the first place (which is why I was asking if make was interrupted). If you touch the source file, delete `compA.o` and run make does `compA.o` stick around at the end?

Comment: Correct and interestingly enough if I mark campA.o as a secondary file it behaves as it did in 3.79. My what I don't understand is that if compA.o is considered an intermediate file when rebuilding is it not considered one in the initial build? Or is there a behavior difference between rebuilding and first build?

Comment: @EtanReisner After touching the source file and deleting compA.o, compA.o was rebuilt and was not deleted, meaning it is not treated as an intermediate file.

Comment: Can you get the relevant lines from the `make -d` output for `compA.o` in that scenario? I don't recall if they will tell us what is going on but they might.

Comment: @EtanReisner I've pulled the relevant info from the -d output, but I'm not sure if it will help much.

Comment: Do you happen to have the target `.SECONDARY` (with no prerequisites) defined in your `makefile`?

Comment: What rule ended up actually building `compA.o`?